# 5 boxen errors when running boxen (our-boxen)

Tags: github, homebrew, boxen

I followed the directions in the our-boxen README but I keep getting 5 errors when I try to run boxen.

I did all of the suggestions suggested on the Homebrew help page (brew install, brew doctor, check that command line tools/xcode is installed).

I have these 4 errors when I try to run boxen. I would create an issue on github but I'm not sure if it's an our-boxen issue or a homebrew issue. Any direction about what type of errors these are would be very helpful.

```
[/opt/boxen/repo]$ ./script/boxen
```

These are the errors I get:

## 1

```
Error: env -i PATH=/opt/boxen/homebrew/bin:/opt/boxen/homebrew/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin CFLAGS=-I/opt/boxen/homebrew/include LDFLAGS=-L/opt/boxen/homebrew/lib /usr/bin/gem install aws-sdk-v1 returned 1 instead of one of [0]
```

## 2

```
Error: /Stage[main]/Crowdtap::Environment/Exec[env -i PATH=/opt/boxen/homebrew/bin:/opt/boxen/homebrew/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin CFLAGS=-I/opt/boxen/homebrew/include LDFLAGS=-L/opt/boxen/homebrew/lib /usr/bin/gem install aws-sdk-v1]/returns: change from notrun to 0 failed: env -i PATH=/opt/boxen/homebrew/bin:/opt/boxen/homebrew/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin CFLAGS=-I/opt/boxen/homebrew/include LDFLAGS=-L/opt/boxen/homebrew/lib /usr/bin/gem install aws-sdk-v1 returned 1 instead of one of [0]
```

## 3

```
Error: Could not update: Execution of 'brew boxen-install boxen/brews/kafka' returned 1: ==> Installing kafka from boxen/brews
==> Downloading http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/apache/kafka/0.8.2.1/kafka-0.8.2.1-src.tgz
Already downloaded: /opt/boxen/cache/homebrew/kafka-0.8.2.1-boxen1.tgz
```

## 4

```
Error: Your OS X keychain GitHub credentials do not have sufficient scope!
Scopes they have: []
Create a personal access token: https://github.com/settings/tokens
and then set HOMEBREW_GITHUB_API_TOKEN as the authentication method instead.
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/utils/github.rb:212:in `raise_api_error': Validation Failed (GitHub::Error)
```

## 5

```
Error: Execution of '/opt/rubies/1.9.3/bin/gem install 'rubocop' --version '~> 0.40' --source 'https://rubygems.org/' --no-rdoc --no-ri --verbose' returned 1: GET http://rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz
```

Has anyone seen this before and know how to solve them?

Answer (score 1):

I realized my mistake. I was trying to clone a repo that I don't have access to, so I switched to cloning the correct boxen repo (https://github.com/boxen/our-boxen). Now this works fine.

```
[~]$ xcode-select --install
[~]$ sudo rm -rf /opt/boxen
[~]$ sudo mkdir -p /opt/boxen
[~]$ sudo chown ${USER}:staff /opt/boxen
[~]$ git clone https://github.com/crowdtap/our-boxen /opt/boxen/repo
[~]$ cd /opt/boxen/repo
[/opt/boxen/repo]$ git remote rm origin
[/opt/boxen/repo]$ git remote add origin git@github.com:lydiastepanek/our-boxen.git
[/opt/boxen/repo]$ git push -u origin master --force
[/opt/boxen/repo]$ ./script/boxen
```